# How to Separate String scanned by Handheld Barcode Scanner?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I stuck in my project. I have searched more but can't find the solution. My problem is when i scanned barcodes more then one from my handheld barcode scanner. I am not getting any such type of character by which i can separate the scanned string to save in array. Is there any way by which i can get the each scanned value separately. Any help will be appreciated. Input can be come from any Handheld/Ring barcode scanner.

Comment: You should see your barcode scanner documentation. They should provide you a delegate method to pass a string or array of strings so after that you can process it. Can you post the code where you receive scanned string?

Comment: @Greg: I am using UIKeyInput Protocol Methods. I am getting the input value character by character. And i am printing them on UIView. This working fine if scanned one time. But More then one input become concat. BarCode scanner can not be specific brand. It can be of any brand.